# What are the default file permissions for the Ubuntu One folder?

Tags: ubuntu-one, permissions

I was playing around with the 'chown' command. In my home folder /home/frank I ran

```
sudo chown -R root 'Ubuntu One'.
```

How can I restore the default file permissions of that folder? I want to be sure that everything synchronises with my Ubuntu One account. So I ran:

```
sudo chown -R frank 'Ubuntu One'.
```

Is that ok?

Inside my Ubunt One folder there's another folder 'Shared with me' that links to another folder. If I run

```
ls -l /home/frank/'Ubuntu one'/'Shared with me'
```

I get this result:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 frank frank     41 mrt  8 04:11 Shared With Me -> /home/frank/.local/share/ubuntuone/shares
```

Are those file permissions ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default permissions on the Ubuntu One folder are 775 and should be tied to your user account. Your last `chown` command is correct to reset the owner to 'frank'.

To reset the proper permissions to the Ubuntu One folders:

`sudo chmod -R 775 /home/frank/Ubuntu\ One`

`sudo chmod -R 555 /home/frank/Ubuntu\ One/Shared\ with\ Me` will reset the permissions to `lr-xr-xr-x` for that folder; you have the correct user and group applied. The default permissions are read-only for items shared with you from another user.